# Calculate percentage by value or value by percentage

Tags: jquery

I have 3 input field to calculate price and discount percentage. First field is for regular price. What I am trying to do is :
If user changes percentage value, discount price will be calculated (2 decimals) and if user changes the discount price, percentage will be calculated.

At the moment I only succeeded calculating the percentage:

```
function calculatePrice() {
    var percentage = $('input[name=\'percentage\']').val(),
        price = $('input[name=\'price\']').val(),
        calcPrice = price - ( (price/100) * percentage ),
        discountPrice = calcPrice.toFixed(2);
    $('input[name=\'discount\']').val(discountPrice);
}
function calculatePerc() {
    var discountPrice = $('input[name=\'discount]\']').val(),
        price = $('input[name=\'price\']').val(),
        calcPerc = (price/100) * (price-discountPrice),
        discountPerc = calcPerc.toFixed();
    $('input[name=\'percentage\']').val(discountPerc);
}
```

My html :

```
<input type="text" name="price" value="1000">
<input type="text" name="percentage" onkeyup="calculatePrice()">
<input type="text" name="discount" onkeyup="calculatePerc()">
```

Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/90bo9okg/

Comment: remove the escape characters. you dont need them. https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/90bo9okg/1/

Comment: @DinoMyte This fiddle works, but I think the intent is to divide discountPerc by 100 (i.e. Post 50.50 instead of 5050)

Comment: Yup. Didn't look at the calculation before. Here's the updated one : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/90bo9okg/2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
// Reusable helper functions
const calculateSale = (listPrice, discount) => {
  listPrice = parseFloat(listPrice);
  discount  = parseFloat(discount);
  return (listPrice - ( listPrice * discount / 100 )).toFixed(2); // Sale price
}
const calculateDiscount = (listPrice, salePrice) => {
  listPrice = parseFloat(listPrice);
  salePrice = parseFloat(salePrice);
  return 100 - (salePrice * 100 / listPrice); // Discount percentage
}

// Our use case
const $list = $('input[name="list"]'),
      $disc = $('input[name="disc"]'), 
      $sale = $('input[name="sale"]'); 
    
$list.add( $disc ).on('input', () => { // List and Discount inputs events
  let sale = $list.val();              // Default to List price
  if ( $disc.val().length ) {          // if value is entered- calculate sale price
    sale = calculateSale($list.val(), $disc.val());
  }
  $sale.val( sale );
});

$sale.on('input', () => {      // Sale input events
  let disc = 0;                // Default to 0%
  if ( $sale.val().length ) {  // if value is entered- calculate the discount
    disc = calculateDiscount($list.val(), $sale.val());
  }
  $disc.val( disc );
});

// Init!
$list.trigger('input');
```

```html
List price: <input type="number" name="list" value="1000"><br>
Discount:   <input type="number" name="disc">%<br>
Sale price: <input type="number" name="sale">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just changed this line 100 - (discount * 100 / price) to (100 - (discount * 100 / price)).toFixed() because when price is something like 103 and discount price is 18 it calculates a strange percentage :)

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a small, quick, and easy piece of javascript code to calculate percentage and round it:

`var percentage = Math.round(((currentValue / goalValue) * 100)) +"%";`

It will return "100" when the fraction returns "1".

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculatePrice() {
    var percentage = $('input[name=\'percentage\']').val(),
    price = $('input[name=\'price\']').val(),
    calcPrice = price - ((price / 100) * percentage),
    discountPrice = calcPrice.toFixed(2); 
    $('input[name=\'discount\']').val(discountPrice);
}

function calculatePerc() {
    var discountPrice = $('input[name=\'discount\']').val(),
    price = $('input[name=\'price\']').val(),
    calcPerc = (price - discountPrice) * 100 / price,
    discountPerc = calcPerc.toFixed(2);
    $('input[name=\'percentage\']').val(discountPerc);
}
```